# JAVA: Generic type compile time constant

Tags: java, generics, numbers, constants

I have an abstract generic class which requires a numeric constant to initialize an array. I know the size of array at compile time when I use that generic class. Is there any way to implement this?

```
abstract class Node<T, MagicN> {

    private T parent    = null;
    private T[] child   = (T[]) new Object[MagicN];

    //some methods that rely on the initialized array.

}
final class ConcreteNode extends Node<ConcreteNodeType, 2> {

}
```

The class ConcreteNode has 2 children in this example.

Comment: What? Your question is really unclear.

Comment: this is not valid : private T[] child   = (T[]) new Object[MagicN];

Comment: I want the to initialize the array with a generic constant value. I can't explain better :(

Comment: Come on, I know this is not valid, it's the reason I named it MAGIC!
This is just an example.

Comment: You can initialize in a constructor, initialization using generic class is not a good idea. MagicN is actually `Integer`

Comment: @haifzhan: If I use a constructor, can I have "some methods that rely on the initialized array" ??

Comment: of course, you can define and implement methods in an abstract class

Comment: This is a really good question. In C++ you can do this. Pity that Java doesn't allow it. For example, I want to make a type `Range<low,high>` which is an integer that is stays between to values, and wraps around using modulus. The low,high ought to be compile-time constants, but Java forces them to be run-time instance data!  Or i could make lots of classes, like Range10_20 and Range5_17 and Range23_28... but that would be absurd.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a Generic as a template.  As Java's code optimisation is done at runtime, there is little reason to have such compile time inlining.

```
abstract class Node<T extends Node> {

    private final T parent;
    private final T[] child;

    Node(T parent, int size) {
        this.parent = parent;
        child = (T[]) new Object[size];
    }

    //some methods that rely on the initialized array.

}
final class ConcreteNode extends Node<ConcreteNode> {
     ConcreteNode(ConcreteNode parent) {
         super(parent, 2);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have values instead of a generic type (or you should have to create a class for each value you may use...)
I think the best in your case would to have a constructor that takes this value as a parameter for example :

```
abstract class Node<T> {

    private T parent    = null;
    private int MagicN = 0;
    private T[] child   = null;

    protected Node(int MagicN)
    {
        this.MagicN = MagicN;
        this.child = (T[]) new Object[MagicN];
    }

    //some methods that rely on the initialized array.

}

final class ConcreteNode extends Node<ConcreteNodeType> {
    public ConcreteNode()
    {
        super(2);
    }
}
```

In terms of performance, there is no difference between what you are trying to do and this example since your child array is initialized in an object context and not a static one.

Answer (score -1):

Why not do it this way?

```
abstract class Node<T> {
    private T parent    = null;
    private T[] child;

    public Node(int childCount) {
        child = (T[]) new Object[childCount];

    //some methods that rely on the initialized array.

}
final class ConcreteNode extends Node<ConcreteNodeType> {
    public ConcreteNode()
    {
        super(2);
    }
}
```